# Controller class source can not be found

Tags: netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using javafx with netbeans as an IDE to develop an app.
When i finished designing the Interface with Scene Builder.
I went back to netbeans, i right clicked on 
FXMLDocument.fxml and clicked make controller, in other to generate the code in FXMLDocumentController.java, a dialog box popped up with an error message "Controller class source cannot be found."

Please has anyone experience this error before. I'm look for a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an FXML file for which this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in the future if I were you.

> I would first right click on the package I want to add a new FXML, and Controller file. Then select "New" and next select "Empty FXML.."

[image]

[image]

> On the next screen pictured below you are given the option to name your FXML file. Hit the "Next" button and check "Use java Controller". You will be given a chance to rename the Java Controller. Hit the "Finish" button if you do not want to add a CSS file.

[image]

From that point, open Scenebuilder and find the FXML file you just create. It should be located inside of your Netbeans project folder.

Comment: I would use this method metioned above to create an empty FXML file. Then I would copy the content from the old FXML file into the new one. You have to be careful not the overwrite the Controller name in the new FXML file.

Comment: Thanks Sedrick for responding to my post. the problem has been solved.